# Putting 2 if statements together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm rather stuck id like to do 2 if statements in side one if-set submit

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        $myName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myName']);
        $mydropdown = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mydropdown']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE id='{$myName}' AND slot='{$mydropdown}'  LIMIT 1 ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    // here we check to see if the username is all ready in the db
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE  slot='{$mydropdown}' AND belongsto = '{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT 1 ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());


        if (mysql_num_rows($result2)==1) { 
            echo 'A monster is all ready in that slot'; 
        }else{
            $battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET slot='{$mydropdown}' WHERE id = '{$myName}'")
                or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

For some odd resson it keeps on doing the else even tho the row count = 1 .
I think i have the { and the } mixed up i have never ever done 2 if staments be for and donno if i can ??

i wanna see if there is a monster in the slot .  The user has 6 slots ok ? And a box. This script picks a monster from the box and inserts the monster into 1 of 6 slots ( which ever slot they pick ) Now i need to make it so if there is all ready a monster in the slot it will not add the monster into the slot because it will get rid of the old monster.....

Comment: you can nest 2 if statements and it appears you are doing it properly. you should double check and make sure result2 really does have only 1 row because i expect it does not if you are seeing your else actions fire

Comment: If statements are nested properly, so there might be a problem with the value of `$result2` variable. +1 for monsters!

Comment: `var_dump(mysql_num_rows ( $result2 ))` what do you get ???

Comment: I have edited the first post / code i wanna see if there is a monster in the slot .  The user has 6 slots ok ? And a box. This script picks a monster from the box and inserts the monster into 1 of 6 slots ( which ever slot they pick ) Now i need to make it so if there is all ready a monster in the slot it will not add the monster into the slot because it will get rid of the old monster.....

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
belongsto = '".$_SESSION{'username'}."'
```

should be:

```
belongsto = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
```

To make the code more readable to other, try to put more and better comments.

Also because of `if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1)`, the else will be ran if there is more than 1 entry as well which I don't think you want that to happen. Maybe you want to put a `>= 1` instead.

Comment: right, accept...lets say for instance it shows up twice in the results because you have a poorly designed query or you somehow managed to let there be duplicate records with the same name. It will also fail and run the else. Your logic is not right.

Comment: It should always at max have 1 entry since it has a `LIMIT 1` clause at the end. I do think the problem is rather, that the queries are not quite doing what he expects... And it's not really clear why `$result` is never used at all.

Comment: I didnt see the LIMIT 1, but the entire logic seems screwed to me.

Comment: I have edited the first post / code i wanna see if there is a monster in the slot .  The user has 6 slots ok ? And a box. This script picks a monster from the box and inserts the monster into 1 of 6 slots ( which ever slot they pick ) Now i need to make it so if there is all ready a monster in the slot it will not add the monster into the slot because it will get rid of the old monster.....

Comment: It's been asked but Ill ask again, what do you get when you var_dump($result2)?

Comment: int(1) A monster is all ready in that slot .    Code now works anyways :) Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

As jgibson says, change the brackets on the $session but also, you do not need to check `num_rows == 1` if you are limiting the query to 1 result, just check if there's a result.  Redundant code can make things messy and harder to debug.

Edited:
Also, why do you have 2 queries and 2 results firing in the same `if` block?  You don't do anything with the first query/result in that block so it should be removed.  as a matter of fact, it doesn't appear you use that query at all, from the code you provide.